# Couldn't update start and end date based on monthly & yearly selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to add start and expire date on monthly & yearly basis for each button. If the monthly is selected, in start date field, current year, date & month should be shown and in the expire date, next month should be shown. If the yearly is selected, in start date field, current year, date & month should be shown and in the expire date, next year should be shown.

The code i have written works only for months. That too in first button only not on every button click. If i change the monthly to yearly, the year is not updating. Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".upgred-frm").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    if ($("#payment-frequency").val() == "monthly") {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
      });
      $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: moment().subtract(-1, "months"),
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss',
      });
    }
    $("#payment-frequency").on("change", function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "monthly") {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
          defaultDate: new Date(),
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
        });
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
          defaultDate: moment().subtract(-1, "months"),
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss',
        });
      } else if ($(this).val() == "yearly") {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
          defaultDate: new Date(),
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
        });
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
          defaultDate: moment().subtract(-1, "years"),
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss',
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  });

  $(".upgred-frm").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).find("form").trigger("reset");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/css/paperindex.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=1"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/5a991bff/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn btn-md btn-default form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".upgred-frm" data-backdrop="static">Upgrade</button>
      <button class="btn btn-md btn-default form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".upgred-frm" data-backdrop="static">Upgrade</button>
      <button class="btn btn-md btn-default form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".upgred-frm" data-backdrop="static">Upgrade</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade upgred-frm" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Upgrade Membership</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group payment-frequency">
            <label for="payment-frequency">Payment Frequency</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="payment-frequency">
              <option>Please select</option>
              <option selected value="monthly">Monthly</option>
              <option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Payment / Trial Start Date</label>
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right"><small class="clr-ccc">The date format should be YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00</small></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="expire-on">Will expire on</label>
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right"><small class="clr-ccc">The date format should be YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00:00</small></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you create new datetimepicker objects instead of changing the options of existing datetimepickers. Every time the `onchange` event fires, you create a new datetimepicker. You can verify that by placing somthing like `console.log('Monthly option selected')` inside your corresponding conditional statement. Each time you change the select to 'Monthly' there will be more lines written to your console because there are more datetimepickers created.

You have to create two datetimepickers at the start of your script and then only change their options instead of creating new ones. This code should give you the expected result:

```
$(function() {
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
 $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
});
$(function() {
$(".upgred-frm").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        if ($("#payment-frequency").val() == "monthly") {
            $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').clear();
            $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').options({
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
            });
            $('#datetimepicker2').data('DateTimePicker').clear();
            $('#datetimepicker2').data('DateTimePicker').options({
            defaultDate: moment().subtract(-1, "months"),
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss',
            });
        }
    });
    $("#payment-frequency").on("change", function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "monthly") {
        $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').clear();
        $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').options({
          defaultDate: new Date(),
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
        });
        $('#datetimepicker2').data('DateTimePicker').clear();
        $('#datetimepicker2').data('DateTimePicker').options({
          defaultDate: moment().subtract(-1, "months"),
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss',
        });
      } else if ($(this).val() == "yearly") {
        $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').clear();
        $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').options({
          defaultDate: new Date(),
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
        });
        $('#datetimepicker2').data('DateTimePicker').clear();
        $('#datetimepicker2').data('DateTimePicker').options({
          defaultDate: moment().subtract(-1, "years"),
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss',
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });

  $(".upgred-frm").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).find("form").trigger("reset");
  });
});
```

Comment: The start & expire fields are empty when the monthly option is selected by default. Thank you :)

Comment: Somehow I forgot to add that part again after I deleted it for testing purposes. Answer edited.

Comment: It Works.Thank you so Much :)